# How do I get different scores for partially matching single-word searches on an InnoDB full text index?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb

I've got the following table in a MySQL 5.6 with an InnoDB full text index.

```
CREATE TABLE `blacklist_entries` (
  `blacklist_entry_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `insertat` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`blacklist_entry_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `ftk_b_n` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=660004 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

This is the data we are dealing with. All the entries in `name` are single words, sometimes with `-`, but never more than one word.

```
mysql> select * from blacklist_entries where name like '%battle%';
+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| blacklist_entry_id | name                | insertat            |
+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|               4159 | battleground        | 2018-01-16 12:15:46 |
|             604218 | battle              | 2018-01-16 12:18:59 |
|             604219 | battlefield         | 2018-01-16 12:18:59 |
|             604220 | battlefields        | 2018-01-16 12:18:59 |
|             604221 | battles             | 2018-01-16 12:18:59 |
|             660003 | abcbattle           | 2018-01-16 12:49:34 |
+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I would like to create a full text search this list that is able to sort by relevance, where a full match has a higher score than a partial match.

When I run this query

```
select
    *,match(name) against ('battle battle* *battle' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score
from blacklist_entries where match(name)
    against ('battle battle* *battle' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I get the following result.

```
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
|     id | name                | insertat            | score              |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
|   4159 | battleground        | 2018-01-16 12:15:46 |  17.11724281311035 |
| 604218 | battle              | 2018-01-16 12:18:59 |  17.11724281311035 |
| 604219 | battlefield         | 2018-01-16 12:18:59 |  17.11724281311035 |
| 604220 | battlefields        | 2018-01-16 12:18:59 |  17.11724281311035 |
| 604221 | battles             | 2018-01-16 12:18:59 |  17.11724281311035 |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
```

There are two issues with this.

- All the results have the same score, even the exact match
- It does not match from the right, and this line is missing

  ```
  | 660003 | abcbattle           | 2018-01-16 12:49:34 |  17.11724281311035 |
  ```

**Can I change something in the query to convince MySQL to do score these matches differently?**

If that is not possible, are there viable alternatives, like implementing  my own scoring in a stored procedure, and iterate the full list again to at least identify the exact match to rank it higher?

If none of these work, I would have to build the scoring in my application layer completely. Obviously that is going to cost additional resources, so I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html

The score is the amount of time the word appears, so for all of them it appears once and it splits the result between.

Answer (score 1):

```
MATCH(name) AGAINST('battle*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    + 0.0001 * (name = 'battle')  AS score
```

That should match all the words in your example, then boost the exact match a little bit.

For boosting when the word is found in the middle of a text  field:

```
   + 0.0001 * (REGEXP '[[:<:]]battle[[:>:]]')
```

(There is nothing special about `0.0001`; it is big enough to change the score, but not so big as to change the "result".)